# Displaying specific Contacts against Account

Tags: apex, visualforce

For an Account showing its related Contacts.I want to show only those contacts which are with status = Active.

I am thinking of putting a filter at the related Contact which only pulls the contacts as Active.{Only want Active Records to be display.} . To do so ,i was planning for the below approaches, but not able to figure out how to go about?

Was thinking on the below approach,but not sure what would be the drawback:: --
1. Setting Record Type : But  figured it out that its only restricted to main record, and was not able to access related list contact in its config setup.

2. Using VisualForce Page, but in pagelayout this page doesn't show up as related list?

   What would be your recommendation on solving this requirement? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A read through this [link](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com.br/2008/10/how-to-create-custom-related-list-on.html), I think he can help you.